# Wifi doesn't work after suspend

Tags: wireless, hp

I have HP Pavilion DV7 6163-us and every time i put the computer to suspense or close the lid, then start it again, the wifi doesn't work. I have to restart the computer every time.
Is there any sudo code that would fix this issue?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: you could try, `Alt+F2` then type `nm-applet` and ENTER. It's always do the trick for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with networking after suspend](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361991/problems-with-networking-after-suspend)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a technique that often works. Find out your wireless driver:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Included in the details for your wireless device will be 'driver=some_driver' Here is an example:

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 35
   serial: xx:94:6b:99:55:yy
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.8.0-26
```

Next, write a configuration file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

Add a single line:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi"
```

Of course, substitute your wireless driver in place of iwlwifi in my example. Proofread, save and close gedit.